# New windows always open with a set size

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

While the initial view opened by the application is the size I expect it to be, every subsequent window opened has a width of 900 and height of 450, regardless of the size of any other window. The only thing that changes the default size is giving the window a set frame size. However, that isn't ideal because I want them to be resizable.

I've determined that the specific size is due to the view having a TextEditor in it, but if I change what the view contains, it still opens to a default size based on the contents, not the size of the last view I opened.

So my question is how do I get the window to open to the size of the last modified window, or a size that I specify, failing that.

Comment: Use `NSWindow` and turn on its `Restorable` switch on.

Comment: I'm using SwiftUI without the UIApplication lifecycle, so that's not an option. I don't directly instantiate the windows.